# Create a csv of file attributes recursively from a directory parameter in PowerShell

Tags: beginner, powershell, properties

I'm a bit new to PowerShell (version 5) and was wondering if there are any improvements I could make to the following script. Any suggestions for style, code, etc. are all welcome.

The script creates a csv of file attributes and extended properties recursively from a directory parameter.  I'm going to then load the csv files into SQL Server.

I'm not sure if there is a more efficient way of filtering the files by last modified date. I need to run it against 30 million files in batches of 500,000.

I've included an example of the UNC path that I use to produce the results file name in the `$searchPath` variable.

I'm currently running this script in a `.bat` file. Is there a better way of running these scripts concurrently?

#### PowerShell Script

```
$searchPath = '\\server\ca$\los angeles\documents\*.*';  #An example of the path format used as a parameter for $args[0]
$resultsFileName = '';
$startDate = '01-Jul-2018';
$endDate = '31-Jul-2019';

$shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application;

#set date defaults
$dateTimeFormat = 'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff';
$executeStart = Get-Date;
$executeStart = $executeStart.ToString($dateTimeFormat);
Write-Host 'Execute Start:' $executeStart;

#get the parent folder from the search path
Write-Host 'Search Path:' $searchPath;
$folder = ($searchPath).Substring(1, ($searchPath).Length - 4);
$parent = Split-Path $folder;

#if the path is not in the expected format dont set the results file name
 if($parent.Length -gt 2)
{
    #get the state name
    $state = Split-Path $parent;
    $state = Split-Path $state -Leaf;
    $state = $state -replace '\$','';
    $state = $state.ToLower();

    #get the office name
    $office = Split-Path $parent -Leaf;
    $office = $office -replace '\W','-';
    $office = $office.ToLower(); 
    $resultsFileName = $state + '_' + $office;
};

#format the result file name and path
$resultFileTimestamp = Get-Date -format 'yyyyMMdd_HHmmss.fff';
if($resultsFileName -eq '') {$resultsFileName = 'results_' + $resultsFileName + '_' + $resultFileTimestamp};

$resultsFile = "C:\Temp\Results\$resultsFileName.csv";
Write-Host 'Results File:' $resultsFile;

    $linenumber = 1;

    #get the file attributes from the recursively from the search path
    Get-Childitem -recurse -Path $searchPath | ? {($_.LastWriteTime -gt $startDate -AND $_.LastWriteTime -lt $endDate) -OR ($_.CreationTime -gt $startDate -AND $_.CreationTime -lt $endDate)}  | ForEach-Object { 
        $fullName = $_.FullName;
        $folder = Split-Path $fullName;
        $file = Split-Path $fullName  -Leaf;
        $shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application;
        $shellfolder = $shell.Namespace($folder);
        $shellfile = $shellfolder.ParseName($file);

        #loop through the extended properties looking for the columns we want
        for ($a ; $a  -le 325; $a++)
           { 
             if($shellfolder.getDetailsOf($File, $a))
               {
                $keyValue = $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($null, $a)
                   switch ( $keyValue )
                    { 
                    'Attributes' { $Attributes = $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, $a) }
                    'Title' { $Title = $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, $a) }
                    'Authors' { $Authors = $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, $a) }
                    'Last printed' { $LastPrinted = $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, $a) }
                    'Date last saved' { $DateLastSaved = $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, $a) }
                    'Pages' { $Pages = $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, $a) }
                    'Word count' { $WordCount = $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, $a) }
                    'Total editing time' { $TotalEditingTime = $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, $a) }
                    'File count' { $FileCount = $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, $a) }
                    }
               } 
           } 
         $a=0;

        #format extended properties
        $LastPrinted = $LastPrinted -replace '[^\p{L}\p{Nd}/(/}/_/:/ ]', ''; #replace non date characters
        if($LastPrinted -ne '') {$LastPrinted = [datetime]::parseexact($LastPrinted, 'd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt', $null).ToString($dateTimeFormat) } else {$LastPrinted = 'NULL'};
        $DateLastSaved = $DateLastSaved -replace '[^\p{L}\p{Nd}/(/}/_/:/ ]', ''; #replace non date characters
        if($DateLastSaved -ne '') {$DateLastSaved = [datetime]::parseexact($DateLastSaved, 'd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt', $null).ToString($dateTimeFormat) } else {$DateLastSaved = 'NULL'};
        $Title = $Title.replace("`n","").replace("`r",""); #remove carriage return line feed from string
        $Authors = $Authors.replace("`n","").replace("`r",""); #remove carriage return line feed from string

        #show the user what file number the script is on
        $currentFileDateTime = Get-Date -format $dateTimeFormat;
        Write-Host $linenumber,  $currentFileDateTime,  $fullName;

        #format the output of the csv file
      Get-Content $fullName | Measure-Object -Character -Word | `
        Select-Object -ExcludeProperty Property `
          @{ Name = 'LineNumber'; Expression={$linenumber}} `
        , @{ Name = 'ExtractTime'; Expression={ Get-Date -format $dateTimeFormat }} `
        , @{ Name = 'FullName'; Expression={ $fullName }} `
        , @{ Name = 'FilePath'; Expression={ $folder }} `
        , @{ Name = 'FileName'; Expression={ $file }} `
        , @{ Name = 'FileSizeKb'; Expression={ (Get-Item $fullName).length / 1024 }} `
        , @{ Name = 'CreationTime'; Expression={(Get-ChildItem $fullName).CreationTime.ToString($dateTimeFormat) }} `
        , @{ Name = 'LastWriteTime'; Expression={(Get-ItemProperty $fullName).LastWriteTime.ToString($dateTimeFormat) }} `
        , @{ Name = 'Attributes'; Expression={ $Attributes.ToString() }} `
        , @{ Name = 'Title'; Expression={ $Title.ToString() }} `
        , @{ Name = 'Authors'; Expression={ $Authors.ToString() }} `
        , @{ Name = 'LastPrinted'; Expression={ $LastPrinted.ToString() }} `
        , @{ Name = 'LastSaved'; Expression={ $DateLastSaved.ToString() }} `
        , @{ Name = 'PageCount'; Expression={ $Pages.ToString() }} `
        , @{ Name = 'WordCount'; Expression={ $WordCount.ToString() }} `
        , Characters `
        , @{ Name = 'TotalEditingTime'; Expression={ $TotalEditingTime.ToString() }} `
        , @{ Name = 'FileCount'; Expression={ $FileCount.ToString() }}; `
        $linenumber ++ `
    } | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $resultsFile;

$executeEnd = Get-Date;
$executeEnd = $executeEnd.ToString($dateTimeFormat);
Write-Host 'Execute End:' $executeEnd;
```

#### Example of CSV file

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What is the purpose of the script?

Comment: To create a CSV of file attributes from multiple directories. I'm going to then load the CSV files into SQL server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `ForEach-Object` and `Where-Object` are slow, you had better to use the `foreach` statement instead of them when working with large data.
Also, because it is useless to get all extended properties, narrow down the property numbers to be obtained in advance.
Although `Select-Object` is useful, it will be slower if you use "calculated property", so it is better to create a new object directly using `[pscustomobject]@{}`.

```
# settings
$startDate = Get-Date "01-Jul-2018"
$endDate = Get-Date "31-Mar-2029"
$resultDir = mkdir "E:\tets\Results" -Force
$dateTimeFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"
$pathList = @(
    "\\server\ca$\los angeles\documents"
    "\\server\ca$\san diego\documents"
    "\\server\ca$\san francisco\documents"
)

$exAttr = @{
    Title = 21
    Authors = 20
    LastPrinted = 200
    LastSaved = 154
    Pages = 157
    WordCount = 160
    TotalEditingTime = 159
    FileCount = 163
}


# start
"Execute Start: {0}" -f (Get-Date -Format $dateTimeFormat) | Write-Host

$shell = New-Object -Com Shell.Application

foreach ($path in $pathList) {

    # create a result file.
    $targetDir = Get-Item -LiteralPath $path
    $resultFileName = "{0}_{1}_{2}.csv" -f @(
        $targetDir.Parent.Parent.Name.TrimEnd("$").ToLower()
        $targetDir.Parent.Name.ToLower() -replace "\W","-"
        Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd_HHmmss.fff
    )
    $resultsFile = New-Item -Path $resultDir -Name $resultFileName -Force

    $lineNumber = 1

    # create customized file information objects.
    $list = foreach ($file in Get-Childitem $targetDir -File -Recurse) {

        if ($file.LastWriteTime -le $startDate -or $file.LastWriteTime -ge $endDate) { continue }

        $exData = @{}

        # get extended properties of office file.
        if ($file.Extension -in ".docx",".xlsx") {
            $dirObj = $shell.NameSpace($file.DirectoryName)
            $itemObj = $dirObj.ParseName($file.Name)
            $exAttr.GetEnumerator() | & { process { $exData[$_.Key] = $dirObj.GetDetailsOf($itemObj, $_.Value) -replace "\p{Cf}" } }

            [void][Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($itemObj)
            [void][Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($dirObj)
        }

        [pscustomobject]@{
            LineNumber = $lineNumber++
            ExtractTime = Get-Date -format $dateTimeFormat
            FullName = $file.FullName
            FilePath = $file.DirectoryName
            FileName = $file.Name
            FileSize = $file.Length / 1KB
            CreationTime = $file.CreationTime.ToString($dateTimeFormat)
            LastWriteTime = $file.LastWriteTime.ToString($dateTimeFormat)
            Attributes = -join ($file.Attributes.Split(",") | & { process { $_.TrimStart()[0] } })
            Title = $exData.Title
            Authors = $exData.Authors
            LastPrinted = if ($exData.LastPrinted) { Get-Date $exData.LastPrinted -Format $dateTimeFormat } else { $null }
            LastSaved = if ($exData.LastSaved) { Get-Date $exData.LastSaved -Format $dateTimeFormat } else { $null }
            PageCount = $exData.Pages
            WordCount = $exData.WordCount
            TotalEditingTime = $exData.TotalEditingTime
            FileCount = $exData.FileCount
        }
    }

    # output to csv file.
    $list | Export-Csv $resultsFile -NoTypeInformation
    $resultsFile
}

[void][Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($shell)

"`nExecute End: {0}`n" -f (Get-Date -Format $dateTimeFormat) | Write-Host
```

If you want to run in parallel, there is a way to use `Start-Job`.

```
$scriptBlock = {
    param(
        $path,
        $startDate,
        $endDate,
        $resultDir,
        $dateTimeFormat
    )

    $exAttr = @{
        ...
    }
    $shell = New-Object -Com Shell.Application

    # create a result file.
    $targetDir = Get-Item -LiteralPath $path
    ...
    ...
}

$pathList | foreach { $i = 0 } { Start-Job -Name $_ -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList $_,$startDate,$endDate,$resultDir,$dateTimeFormat }
```

If file retrieval and filtering is a bottleneck, you can write partially in C#.

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class MyFileIO
{
    public static List<FileInfo> GetFiles(DirectoryInfo dir, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        var files = new List<FileInfo>();
        var queue = new Queue<DirectoryInfo>();
        queue.Enqueue(dir);
        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            dir = queue.Dequeue();
            foreach (var subDir in dir.GetDirectories()) queue.Enqueue(subDir);
            foreach(var file in dir.GetFiles())
                if(file.LastWriteTime > startDate && file.LastWriteTime < endDate) files.Add(file);
        }
        return files;
    }
}
"@

foreach ($file in [MyFileIO]::GetFiles($targetDir, $startDate, $endDate)) {
    ...
}
```